# Java Spring declare bean in service class

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have Spring Java `Services` class with a lot of beans:

```
@Service ("employeeManager")
public class EmployeeManagerImpl implements EmployeeManager
{
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAO employeedao;

    @Autowired
    Workerdao workerdao;

    @Autowired
    SallaeryDao sallaeryDao

    @Autowired
    TaxDao taxDao

    @Autowired
    HouresDao houresDao

    @Autowired

    *****Dao

    public EmployeeDTO createNewEmployee()
    {
        return dao.createNewEmployee();
    }
}
```

Can I clean the `Service` class code without a lot of bean declare in my class that I will have only one bean? I have a lot of bean and I don't want to declare them in the class with

Comment: You don't want to declare them in class, but you still need them in class implementation? Or you don't need them at all?

Comment: This is actually a design issue. Your class is doing a lot of things. You need to split your code into separate focused classes. For example create a separate SalaryManager service class which deals with salary related concerns